# Search from the saved MarkupStrings of Emails using entity framework filters

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I am developing an application of Blzaor Server .NET Core in which I am maintaining a backup or history of all the emails sent. For saving the emails, I am saving the whole MarkupString(HTML String) of the email.

I want to search text in the MarkupString of the email using EF Core filters.

The problem that I am facing is that I am trying to search for a simple text from the HTML. For example, if I search "I am playing Cricket" then in the markup string it can be something like .

[image]

"I am playing **Cricket**" so "I am playing **Cricket**".Contain("I am playing Cricket") will return false.

As I am using EF filters so Its an expression and we can't make conversions of MarkUp string to simple text in the expression (EF core does not allow that).

I don't know how to achieve this. Can someone help, please?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What has this go to do with Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag)? Since you want to search the unformatted text of the message then have you considered using Html Agility Pack to parse the HTML, then search the plain text returned from HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.InnerText?

Comment: As I have to do it using Filters of EF core i.e. filtering at the time of data coming from the database so I will hv to do something like sql functions may b. Thats why added this tag. 

I cant use Html Agility Pack to parse cuz the filter of EF core asks for an expression and any kind of parsing in the expression is not allowed and throws exception

Comment: Have you considered storing the plain text for searches in the DB, so you only parse the HTML once up front?

Comment: Yeah I had a thought of doing that but it will then come in duplicate data. As I will have to consider two fields of table now one MarkUp String and the other one is plain text.